# Postfix: outgoing email error

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, email-bounces

Email send but not reached the receiver's mailbox, mainly for Google, Microsoft, and yahoo.
Already checked blocklisted or not, but no blocked there.
**mail queue** is mentioned below.

C6A02490A1    11809 Mon Jan  2 10:21:19  arijul.haque@saraswationline.com
(delivery temporarily suspended: connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.171.26]:25: Connection timed out)
arijul.saraswationline@gmail.com

Comment: Are you sure your provider allows port 25 outgoing?

Comment: You mentioned a few destinations that *don't* work, you might want to look the other way: Any internet destination that *do work*? In any case, review the documentation of your hosting provider, if they restrict your usage, they will usually say clearly what they do and legitimate use cases may have such restrictions lifted.

Comment: I am using AWS. From the server, I checked telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25 but the result showed "telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable". Please suggest to me the way how I can resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

For mail servers to receive your email, there multiple DNS stuff you must go for.

1. define SPF record
2. define Reveres record

Note: make sure your email server address is not listed in any DNSBL via the link below:

[SPAM DATABASE LOOKUP](https://www.dnsbl.info/dnsbl-database-check.php)

There are also some other records needed, but Minimum with defining those above you will be able to transfer your emails to Google,Microsoft and others...